# When I have multiple UI elements overlapping, how can I use a raycast to prioritize the one on top?

Tags: unity, gui, raycasting

I have movable objects in a scene.  When Raycast hits an object, I have a hovering UI that moves to a retaliative distance from the hit object.  When the object is dragged, the UI's position is moved relative to the object.  The UI accesses script functions by way of the Button(Script) component.  I attached my functions to the buttons in the editor.

My issue is when the hovering UI is overlapping the view of another object, the UI moves to the object under the UI and never performed the function.
I would like for raycast never to hit the underlying object while my hovering UI is up, or at least to not hit the underlying object while the UI is in the way.

[image]

Both scripts are attached to the object tiles.

**updatePentagon.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class updatePentagon : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    public GameObject UI;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    private Plane dragPlane;
    private Vector3 dragPlaneNormal = Vector3.up;
    private float distanceToDragPlane = 0;
    Ray ray;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 100f) ) {
                //if ((hit.collider.tag == "tileUI")  ){
                    //UI.SetActive (true);
                    target = hit.transform;
                    dragPlane = new Plane (dragPlaneNormal, target.position);
                //}
            }
        }
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
                ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
                if (target) {
                    if (dragPlane.Raycast (ray, out distanceToDragPlane)) {
                        target.position = ray.GetPoint (distanceToDragPlane);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**updateTileUI.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class updateTileUI : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject tileHandler;
    updatePentagon updatePentagon;
    float UIoffset = .2f;
    Vector3 pos;

    void Start () {
        updatePentagon = GetComponent<updatePentagon> ();
        updatePentagon.target.Rotate(0, 36, 0);
        updatePentagon.target.Rotate(0, -36, 0);
    }
    void Update () {
    }
    void OnMouseDown(){
        updatePentagon = GetComponent<updatePentagon> ();
        pos = updatePentagon.target.position;
        pos.y = updatePentagon.target.position.y + UIoffset;
        tileHandler.SetActive (true);
        tileHandler.transform.position = pos;
        }
    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        tileHandler.transform.position = updatePentagon.target.position + new Vector3(0, UIoffset, 0);
    }
    public void cancelUI(){
        tileHandler.SetActive (false);
    }
    public void turnRight(){
        updatePentagon.target.Rotate(0, 36, 0);
        }
    public void turnLeft(){
        updatePentagon.target.Rotate(0, -36, 0);
    }
    public void confirm(){
        //activate colliders
        tileHandler.SetActive (false);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have the UI set a flag that it has been click on, and condition the tiles to not respond to an intercepted mouse click.  It may be useful in the future when you click units, or other things you might implement that are on top of your tiles.  Perhaps all things should be able to intercept clicks and set this flag.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is to get the click ray, do a `Physics.RaycastAll()` and run through each object sequentially. The following is 2 scripts I used.

RayShooter.cs

```
public class RayShooter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Ray ray; 
    public float distance = 10;

    void Start () {
        ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    }

    void Update () {
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * distance ,Color.red); 

        RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray, distance);

        foreach (var hit in hits)
        {
            bool blocked = hit.collider.GetComponent<RayIntercepter>().ProcessHit();

            if (blocked)
            {
                Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hit.point, Color.green);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RayIntercepter.cs

```
public class RayIntercepter : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool doProcessHit;
    public bool doInterceptHit;

    public bool ProcessHit()
    {
        if (!doProcessHit) { return false; } //This object doesnt want to get hit now

        //When I get hit, I draw line (Change this to whatever you want)
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position+ Vector3.up*2, Color.yellow);

        if (doInterceptHit) return true; //Block the raycast
        return false; //Dont block the raycast
    }
}
```

Here is a test scene

[image]

Yellow line = Ray process
Green line = Actual ray hits
Red line = Potential ray hit

From the left, the following is the properties

1. DoProcessHit = false, DoInterceptHit = false;
2. DoProcessHit = true, DoInterceptHit = false;
3. DoProcessHit = true, DoInterceptHit = true;
4. DoProcessHit = true, DoInterceptHit = true;

Describing each object,

- The first object ignores all raycast.
- The second object processes the raycast but doesnt block it
- The third object processes the raycast and blocks it
- The forth object want to process raycast but didnt receive it.

The suggestion for a camera case is to use `Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay()` to get the ray for the ray shooter.

Answer (score 0):

If your hovering panel is a UI object (that is, one that uses the [new Unity UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui) and requires a Canvas to render; I am unable to tell if you are or not) then you can do this at the top of your click-handling function:

```
if(EventSystem.current != null && EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject != null) {
    return;
}
```

In your case, it'd be the section of code with the raycast in it. You can put this above the raycast and the rest of the method will be skipped.